Why does Divider Generator output an unknown x?
I'm a beginner in FPGA programming and I'm trying to implement a noise filter in Verilog on Vivado. I'm doing calculations on the input signal where division is needed, so I'm using the Divider Generator IP to implement the division outside of a module. When I run behavioral simulation, I get an unknown output x from the Divider Generator, even though the input data is valid. I'm guessing that I'm implementing the division wrong with the IP, but does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I hardly did any coding about the Division Generator and most I did was connecting the input an output ports.
Here is my code (here is also the full version of the code):
reg [15:0] y, y_init, u; 
reg [15:0] x_curr, x_curr0, x_curr1, x_curr2, x_next, x_next2, x_next3;
reg [15:0] e_pre_var, e_next_var, e_next_var1, e_next_var2;
reg [15:0] K_pre, K_next, one_K_next_sq, K_next_sq; // kalman gain

always@(posedge clk) begin
// distribute calculations over multiple clock cycles to meet timing
// all variables that are not declared as reg are parameters
    
        if (counter == 9) begin
                y_init = y_measured;
        end
        if (counter == 10) begin
                x_next2 = k_omega*y_init;
                x_next3 = oT*x_next2;
                measured = x_next3;
        end
        if (counter == 11) begin
                x_next = x_next1 - x_next3; // predict the next state x_n
                e_pre_var = e_pre_var0;  
        end

// counter1024 counts up to 1024 clock cycles, so the following makes calculations every 1024 //cycles
// this reduces the calculation rate from 125 MHz            
        if (counter_eq_1024) begin             
            y = y_measured;
            u = -oT*k_omega*y;
        end
        if (counter1024 == 1) begin
            K_next_num = (phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var);
            K_next_denom = (phi_sq*e_pre_var + d_var + s_var);
//            K_next = K_next_num / K_next_denom;
            M_AXIS_OUT_tvalid_kal = 1'b1; // send the numerator and denominator values to the Divider Generator
            K_next = K_next_in;
        end 
        if (counter1024 == 2) begin
            x_curr0 = 1-K_next;
            x_curr1 = x_curr0*x_next;
            x_curr2 = K_next*y;
        end 
        if (counter1024 == 3) begin
            x_curr = x_curr1 + x_curr2; // estimate the current state
            
            x_next = phi*x_curr + u; // predict the next state    
        end 
        if (counter1024 == 4) begin
            one_K_next_sq = (1-K_next)*(1-K_next);
            K_next_sq = K_next*K_next;
        end
        if(counter1024 == 5) begin
            e_next_var1 = one_K_next_sq*K_next_num;
            e_next_var2 = K_next_sq*s_var;
            e_next_var = e_next_var1 + e_next_var2;
            
        end
        if (counter1024 == 6) begin

            // make the next values the old values for next cycle
            K_pre = K_next;
            e_pre_var = e_next_var;
     
            
            // Assign the calculated value to the output signal
            M_AXIS_OUT_tdata = x_next;
            
            // Store sampled data in memory
            x_data = x_next;
            
            M_AXIS_OUT_tvalid_kal = 1'b0; // stop data flow to Divider Generator

        end
    end



Your divider uses AXI streams for its input and output. You can't just ignore the handshaking signals TREADY and TVALID on these interfaces. In particular, if you never assert TREADY at the output, it won't produce any data. And if you don't watch TVALID, you won't know on which clock cycle your data pops out.
If you aren't familiar with how AXI streams work, the article "AXI Basics 1 - Introduction to AXI" might be a good place to start.
